# Caching in HTML 5

Tags: html, caching

I'm trying to use caching, but I'm not sure why I'm implementing it right. When I see Page Speed tool from Google Developers, it still tells me my images are not being cached. Here's my code:

**HTML**:

```
<html lang="en" manifest="manifest.appcache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=86400">
...
```

**manifest.appcache**:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2015-05-27

#Static FILES
css/bootstrap.min.css
js/bootstrap.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js

#Static IMGS
img/desktop_homepage.jpg
img/mobile_homepage.jpg
img/tablet_homepage.jpg
img/cargo_arrow.png
img/minus.png
img/plus.png
img/countries/at.png
img/countries/be.png
img/countries/canada.png
img/countries/ch.png
img/countries/cz.png
img/countries/de.png
img/countries/es.png
img/countries/fr.png
img/countries/gb.png
img/countries/gr.png
img/countries/hu.png
img/countries/ie.png
img/countries/it.png
img/countries/nl.png
img/countries/pt.png
img/countries/usa.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your server to send the images with the `last-modified`, `max-age` or `etag` tag.

Check this page: [optimize with caching](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/)